# What is the point of using refresh token instead of username password pairs?

Tags: oauth, refresh-token

I understand the benefit that if we use a refresh token, the requests containing credentials or refresh tokens are reduced hugely because a client to do some meaningful job in our services can send numerous requests during a period stipulated by an access token. For example, I can send 100 requests in 5 minutes once I attain an access token. Those 100 requests do not contain my credentials, so the security has increased.

My question is what are the benefits of using refresh tokens instead of username and password pair?

I've read many answers and articles about this but they cannot go beyond reiterating that we don't have to expose our credentials through refresh tokens. But who cares about the credentials as long as I got the refresh token? I might as well send my username and password to get a new access token. It effectively supplants the credentials for authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A refresh token still only has restricted privileges, scoped to the client application. It allows you to get new access tokens with privileges (scopes and claims) the app needs, for the lifetime of the user session.

Example properties might be as follows:

- Refresh token lifetime: 4 hours
- Access token lifetime: 30 minutes
- Access token scopes: orders_write benefits_read
- subject claim: user123
- subscription_level claim: silver

When access tokens are played against APIs, the API's authorization logic restricts logic based on scopes and claims in the token. Eg the user can only access their own orders or benefits their subscription level allows.

Whereas a user's credentials might be usable across many apps, some of which have more sensitive privileges.